# failed: File name too longDomain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to run my project and it gives me the following error:
[image]

This is the detailed error:

```
Details

copyfile of file:///Users/Arturo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StyleOn-gnaveysksvvzgjehhtqxncocfede/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/StyleOn.app to file:///Users/Arturo/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/14BA1179-CD3E-426E-8918-085B4E028B1E/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.installcoordinationd/Library/InstallCoordination/PromiseStaging/DE0A7C4A-FDE7-4159-B9A3-A5F6627D782C/StyleOn.app failed: File name too long
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 63
Failure Reason: Unhandled error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code 63
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[IXFileManager _copyItemAtURL:toURL:failIfSrcMissing:error:]";
    SourceFileLine = 186;
}
--
```

What can I do?

Comment: Try to close Xcode and clear DerivedData: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, maybe it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way it solved it was by closing Xcode and clear DerivedData:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`